# how to convert datetime value to another date only format?

Tags: sql, datetime

my datetime field looks like this:

```
 2011-02-07 06:51:32.000 (yyyy-mm-dd)
```

User input is in this format:

```
 02-07-2011 (only the date)
```

This should be converted to:

```
 02-07-2011 00:00:00.000
```

i tried CONVERT:

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),myDateTimeField,113)
```

but this only works with date values not with datetime.

please help!

I used the following function:

```
CONVERT(datetime,Cast(myDateInput AS Char (10)), 105)
```

thanks for all your answers! and my apoligizes for changing my question!

Comment: But what product? MySQL? Oracle? ...

Comment: hmmm, i'm using Microsoft SQL Server management studio. Does it make a difference? Convert functions are the same for every SQl distribution right? EDIT: Sorry, it does. i'm using MSSQL

Comment: @jorrebor every database management system has its own functions

Comment: Actually there is something called standard SQL, but it does not effect really types and functions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization

Answer (score 2):

select convert(varchar, myDateTimeField, 105) ...

Source: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Crystal has a function called `Date`; it takes either YYYY, MM, DD or a datetime as arguments and returns a date.

So I would suggest you make a formula to change the date to a datetime and display it.

```
date( mytable.mydatetimevar )
```

You should then be able to format this date as you want with the normal date field formatting options.

An alternative method of doing it is using Crystal's DatePart function to pull out the month, year, day and then restructure as required.

Comment: yes that's possible but this is the parameter field. I want data to be selected based on these dates. I realize now that i made a mistake. The conversion should be the other way around. see my edit

Comment: I didn't realise this was prior to being inserted into Crystal.  You can still pass a datetime parameter and convert it before being used to select records inside of crystal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select DATEPART(mm, myDateTimeField) + '-' +
       DATEPART(dd, myDateTimeField) + '-' +
       DATEPART(year, myDateTimeField)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's surprising that a `DATETIME` field carries time information ;)

In fact, you shouldn't alter the field itself, as you would lose the database engine's ability to use date/time related functions with this field. 
(the format used is ISO 8601 which helps the engine to easily identify the single parts)

As others said, it's good practice to format the date when you are retrieving it, either in your `SELECT` statement or in your application. (for more tips regarding this we would indeed need the information what sql server and what appliccation language you are using).

Comment: I dont want to convert the field permantly, i dont think i even have permissions for doing so :). But making the conversion once in the where clause would increase performance as opposed to doing a conversion in the select clause right?

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference - the conversion would be made per row anyway. It's more a question if you just need the conversion to filter the entries (WHERE) or if you want to display/use the date after recieving the entries (SELECT). Fastes solution would probably be to convert your search criteria to ISO 8601 to match the DATETIME format

Answer (score 0):

try converting with Style ID - 110

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),myDateTimeField,110)
```

Result will be: 02-07-2011